# Pc-lint doesnt understand types from a included header file

Tags: c, static-analysis, lint, pc-lint

I'm trying to use PC-lint on a large C project that uses a 3rd party compiler (TASKING TriCore v4.1r2). 
Lint reports loads of errors but most of them seem to be just lint not working properly, which is probably due to my configuration. So im wondering if anyone can see anything that would cause (or knows how to prevent) following errors:

I've got a header file with some typedefs like this:

```
#ifndef FOO_TYPES_H
#define FOO_TYPES_H 
typedef unsigned char U8;
typedef unsigned long U32;
#endif
```

In the lint output, i can see that the file is being processed, and it seems to pass with no errors. 
Next file being processed includes the above one as:

```
#include "foo_types.h"
```

In this second file ive got a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{  
    U8   v1;     
    U32  v2;   
} FOO_STRUCT;
```

But lint gives me errors like these:

```
Warning Line 71: No explicit type for symbol 'FOO_STRUCT::U32', int assumed. Lint code: 601
Error Line 71: Expecting ';'. Lint code: 10
```

This would indicate to me that it didnt recognise the included file "foo_types.h", and obviously this causes loads of problems further down the line.
The .c file that im linting looks something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo_types.h"

void bar(U8 v1, U32 v2)
{
    FOO_STRUCT s;
    s.v1 = v1;
    s.v2 = v2;
}
```

Ive specified all of the include folders in my std.lnt and they are definitely being processed. When i run lint with -p option, i can see that it does go through the whole list of includes before it starts processing a .c module.

Also the file names are unique so that shouldn't cause issues.

EDIT:
file: stdlib.h

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;
//some more definitions that it doesnt complain about here ..
//next line causes lint to complain
extern void * calloc(size_t,size_t)__malloc__;
```

This is what lint says:

```
Note Line 70: Function 'calloc' defined without a prototype in scope. Lint code: 957
Error line 70: Expecting ';'. Lint code: 10
```

There is no previous mention of calloc or **malloc** in this file and it doesnt include anything else.
Is there a way to make lint see that this in not a error?

EDIT2:
These are the options im using, which is probably where the problem truly lies:

```
//Most of this stuff i got from a colleague
-DKB_SCHEDULER=1;BIT_BASHED_DALLAS=1;IBC_DEV_CID_CTRL=1;SW_CLOCK_TICK_PERIOD_MS=8;RTC_HW_FITTED=1;__CTC__=1;OSC_FREQ_MHZ=20;TX_DELAY_ACTIVE;CTRL_CPU=1;CPU_FREQ_MHZ=300;ZEROED_CRC=1;TC1798_CPU;BCU_BUILD=1;NEW_COM_CAN_LINK=1;__MODEL__=1;__nop=_nop_;__align()=;
// Handle some of the non standard compiler keywords for the Tasking 
//compiler on the Tri-core.
-d__attribute__()=
+rw(_bit) -dsbit=_bit -e537 -e534
-pragma(message)    // do not issue pragma messages
-esym(950, sdata,bdata,idata,huge,xhuge,far,near)
// Don't stop make because of warnings
-zero(99)
//suppress ANSI/ISO limit of 6 'significant characters in an external 
//identifier', 'trace_buffer', exceeded -- processing is unaffected Info
-e793
-esym(960, 17.4)   // MISRA Rule 17.4 - Pointer arithmetic other than array 
//indexing used does not seem to work on PC Lint.
-emacro(960,TRUE)
-emacro(961,TRUE)
-emacro(506,TRUE)
-emacro(960,FALSE)
-emacro(961,FALSE)
-emacro(506,FALSE)
-emacro(960,ASSERT_RELEASE)
-emacro(961,ASSERT_RELEASE)
-esym(718,__mfcr)
-esym(746,__mfcr)
-esym(960,__mfcr)
-esym(718,__mtcr)
-esym(746,__mtcr)
-esym(960,__mtcr)
-d__interrupt(x)=
-d__trap(x)=
-dinline=
-d__noinline=

-mD -si2 -spN2 -spF4 +libclass( angle )
```

Any tips on how to approach fixing this problem would be much appreciated, eg. what to check first, what to change first etc

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but if you take the output from the preprocessor (ie using gcc -E), does it still not find the U8 datatype?

Comment: From what you show this is merely reproduceable (What you show just defines `U8`, so Lint is expected to complain about `U32` missing). Please provide a consistent example.

Comment: I don't think this is showing enough of the source code to exhibit what the root cause is. If I simply create a `kb_types.h` with a couple of typedefs to define `U8` and `U32` and define the structure type as shown, it doesn't exhibit any warnings. So it's likely that something else in your `kb_types.h` header file, or some other part of your .c file or other header file,is the root cause of this error.

Comment: @alk The code base is massive, but ill write up a small example that would be similar and try to run it with my options. Then ill post the results here. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Saving the preprocessed output in a file and running lint on it gives the same errors

Comment: @lurker Is it possible that it is compiler issue? Because im using this TriCore compiler and lint actually finds this problem in its stdlib.h: Note Line 70: Function 'calloc' defined without a prototype in scope [MISRA 2004 Rule 8.1]   followed by Error Line 70: Expecting ';' . I'll edit the question to show this + code

Comment: From your prior comment: *The code base is massive, but ill write up a small example*. This is the right approach. It is essential in a question/problem like this that you try to reduce it down. Make a sample source file with *just* the code in question and nothing else and see if you get the same results. It might be a compiler issue of you're using an odd-ball compiler, but I doubt it unless the problem has been simplified greatly and shown still to occur.

Comment: @lurker Just tried again with a small example, if i omit the #include <stdlib.h> , there is no error. But with it included there are loads of nonsense errors and that is with both the TriCore compiler and with Visual C. Ill post the list of options im using in the edit because that is probably the issue

Comment: @MilosMatovic Does it give you error like "Unable to find foo_types.h" in the lint log? Sometimes, Lint prints all the information and mentions this error? When you run with `-p`, does it shows correct path of folder where foo_types.h? 
Assuming you are declaring `FOO_Struct` in foo.h, Are you including "foo_types.h" in "foo.h" so that it will know what is U32?

Comment: @Swanand It finds all the includes fine, ive checked the preprocessed output and they are all there. At this point im 100% certain that it is something to do with compiler options. Gimpel normally provides these to customers in form of co-*.lnt but they dont have one for the compiler im using so just have to figure it out myself.

Comment: @MilosMatovic I recreated same situation on Tasking and didn't get any error! Probably not related to compiler. If you are including "foo_types.h" AFTER <stdio.h>, you may get the error. But if you change the order, it should not give you an error. Reason Unknown